# JQuery - migration to 1.9 caused dialog buttons not to display text

Tags: jquery

I am working on a legacy application, and upgraded jquery from 1.6.2 to 1.9.1
I used the migrate.js to resolve the deprecated code.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The following javscript brings up a dialog box;

```
jQuery.fn.jDialogWrapper("Please enter the worked hours(should not be zero), for the entered the Contract Number or Description.").dialog('open');
```

where the function is defined as follows;

```
jQuery.fn.jDialogWrapper = function (message) {
    return $('<div class="StasDialogClass"></div>')
        .html(message)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            dialogClass: 'StasDialogClass',
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Mulalley STAS',
            buttons: {
                OK: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
};
```

When the dialog message is disaplyed, the OK button has no text in it. It should say OK.
How do I fix this?

Comment: `dialog()` is part of jQueryUI - have you updated that to the latest version too?

Comment: I upgraded it to jquery-ui-1.8.24

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3HYgz/ any error in the console?

Comment: Yes that works it is baffling. Does it matter what version of jquery-ui is being used? The examples I find use 1.10.3. However when i use that I get another bug  in that the extend() method of widget is undefined